# how to solve an error related pylint installltion on vs code stdio

Tags: python-3.x

```
C:\Users\home\Desktop\projectF\Voice-Based-Email-For-ThenBlind- 
master>C:/Python34/python.exe -m
pip install -U pylint --user
Downloading/unpacking pylint 
Downloading/unpacking isort>=4.2.5,<5 (from pylint)
Downloading/unpacking astroid>=2.3.0,<2.4 (from pylint)
Cleaning up...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site- 
  packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources.py", line 2421, in _dep_map
    return self.__dep_map
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-
```

packages\pip_vendor\pkg_resources.py", line 2283, in **getattr**
        raise AttributeError(attr) 
    AttributeError: _DistInfoDistribution__dep_map

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception 
occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 
122, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", 
line 278, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, 
force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 1265, in 
prepare_files
    req_to_install.extras):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site- 
packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources.py", line 2232, in requires
    dm = self._dep_map
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-
```

packages\pip_vendor\pkg_resources.py", line 2423, in _dep_map
        self.__dep_map = self._compute_dependencies()
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site- 
   packages\pip_vendor\pkg_resources.py", line 2447, in _ 
     compute_dependencies
         parsed = next(parse_requirements(distvers))
       File "C:\Python34\lib\site- 
     packages\pip_vendor\pkg_resources.py", line 2544, in 
     parse_requirements
         line, p, specs = scan_list(VERSION,LINE_END,line,p, 
     (1,2),"version spec")
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site- 
   packages\pip_vendor\pkg_resources.py", line 2522, in scan_list
        "Expected ',' or end-of-list in",line,"at",line[p:]
    ValueError: ("Expected ',' or end-of-list in", 'lazy-object-proxy 
    ==1.4.*', 'at', '*')

Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\home\pip\pip.log

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same issue on my Ubuntu 14.04 VM when I tried to install pylint. There was error saying "UserWarning: Unknown distribution option", which indicates the verison of my setuptools might be too old. But update didn't fix the issue. So I tried to download the source file from the project page [lazy-object-proxy.1.4.3 zip file](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/07/3f/a3d687f83c7d44970f70ff0400677746c8860b11f0c08f6b4e07205f0cdc/lazy-object-proxy-1.4.3.tar.gz)
After download the zip file, simply installed by the zip file solved my problem:

```
pip install PATH_TO_THE_ZIP_FILE
```